# Multiboot with windows

Tags: root-access

I would like to multiboot my SM-T210 with Windows 8.1 and Android.
I have a windows 8.1 ISO file,A rooted SM-T210.

I do not want to remove android from my tablet because of all my game progress and i do not want to restart my progress in games.

Answer (score 3):

No, currently, it is not possible. On smartphone software, the operating system is tied into the device's BIOS and configuration. You can only run Android/UNIX OS's that were built for that mobile device.

See @RyanConrad's comment for more info:

> … Normal Windows will not run on ARM which is the type of CPU this device has. And even if hypothetically you got it to run, Windows would likely not have drivers for the hardware like camera, touchscreen, and other chipsets. Not to mention the device as 1GB of RAM, and Windows doesn't run very well with that little RAM.

Alternatively, you can install an app like [Complete Linux Installer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zpwebsites.linuxonandroid&hl=en) or [Debian noroot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cuntubuntu&hl=en) to install an *emulated* desktop Linux.

Comment: It goes beyond this. Normal windows will not run on ARM which is the type of CPU this device has. And even if hypothetically you got it to run, windows would likely not have drivers for the hardware like camera, touchscreen, and other chipsets. Not to mention the device as 1GB of RAM, and windows doesn't run very well with that little RAM.

Comment: Thanks, I was using "BIOS" as a general term for configuration, but you're right. I added your comment to the answer.